# Apache web server localhost works but IP gives error code 404

Tags: apache

When I use localhost the index page is displayed.  When I use the IP outside of my network or within my network I get a not found 404 error.  Please suggest possible issues or fixes.

Comment: Either you have setup a virtual host, or this is a firewall issue. Ask again in serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

disable iptables or open up port 80.  To check to see if this is the problem type:

```
service iptables save
service iptables stop
```

Comment: is there an equivalent to this in Windows?

Comment: yes, you can adjust the windows firewall settings in the control panel.  if you installed wamp from metapackage you should also click 'put online' in the launcher.